# in RMANOVA, are the subjects dependent?

Tags: repeated-measures

I want to perform a RMANOVA, are the subjects that the experiments are gonna be performed on, dependent?

Comment: Are you about RM-ANOVA? Or RM-MANOVA? Or maybe some R-MANOVA?

Comment: @ttnphns  I'm talking about a pepeated measures ANOVA

Answer (score 1):

The design calls for paired observations, not indviduals. Therefore, your observations are dependent by virtue of multiple measures on the same individual. The individuals themselves are assumed to be independent (though there are designs where they too need not be).

Comment: The individuals them selves are independent of what? and what are the cases where  they too need not be?

Comment: The individuals are independent of themselves, such as a random sample of a population. It's easy to think of situations where individuals are also correlated, such as sampling sibling pairs within families. These are further "wrinkles" on the same basic problem. Since you haven't stated where your population comes from, this is the default answer with any basic repeated measures model.